# stm32H7 SDMMC1 Falling and rising edge

Tags: stm32, sd, hal

I'm trying to make my sdmmc1 project read cmd data by rising edge, what i have tried:

1. Tried both  **hsd1.Init.ClockEdge = SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING**; and  **hsd1.Init.ClockEdge = SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_FALLING**
2. Tried to configure mmc 1 bit and sd mmc 1 bit
3. Tried diffrent clock freq (200 mhz and 20 mhz)
4. checked SDMMC registers, especially SDMMC_CLKCR, NEGEDGE bit is not set:
   [image]
   CODE:

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init(void);

```
while (1)
  {
    if (UserRxBufferFS[0] == 0x97) // got the command
        {  
            UserRxBufferFS[0] = 0;

            MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init();
        }
  }


 static void MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 1 */
  hsd1.Instance = SDMMC1;
  hsd1.Init.ClockEdge = SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
  hsd1.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDMMC_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
  hsd1.Init.BusWide = SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_1B;
  hsd1.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDMMC_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;
  hsd1.Init.ClockDiv = 0;
  if (HAL_SD_Init(&hsd1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 2 */

}
```

I'm always getting edge like below:
[image]

While im looking for edge like this:
[image]
Why **SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_FALLING;** or **SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;** doesnt change anything?